# Securing WS endpoints & apis in IBM Bluemix

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

We are building an app that will be hosted in IBM Bluemix. The front end will be secured using IBM SSO. We are struggling to understand how to secure our APIs and Bluemix support has not been very helpful. My understanding is that CloudFoundry offers UAA which can be used to secure our APIs using OAuth. If this is the solution, how can this be used in a Bluemix environment?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a specific example? One of the issues with getting you support on this SSO issue here is that the post is not tagged for that technology and the edit flag is greyed out so I cannot add it for you. Please add the single-sign-on tag so that the SSO service team will be aware of the post. I'll also contact them on your behalf.

Comment: Didn't think SSO would be the solution for securing the APIs themselves, but added the tag. Any support would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please be aware that this question was asked on dW Answers where more information was provided: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/380140/securing-web-services-apis-in-bluemix-oauth.html

Comment: Hi Bill - please see my response there. The answer and info provided is inaccurate. This is a common scenario in cloud solutions. It would be to IBMs benefit to publish clear and open guidance on this very common problem. The lack of support, information and resources by far has been my biggest barrier towards adopting Bluemix.